# How to avoid headers being modified by nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, php-fpm

I am hosting a laravel web app which serves a few APIs to other clients. This application extensively uses HTTP headers. I could notice that, when the app is hosted in nginx, headers are coming a bit different.

1. Headers come in sentence case. (token becomes Token)
2. Underscores become minux. (handle_id becomes Handle-Id)

I have enabled `underscores_in_headers on` for this box.

Is there a way to avoid nginx changing the letter casing and underscores (to minus)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why can't you switch to `Apache`?  it's in the Amazon Linux repository and i'm sure there are custom packaged AMIs for it if that's your thing.

Comment: I have some node applications as well to run, which needs a reverse proxy. So, I was thinking why not to run both php and node on nginx. Does that have any problem?